# How do you find the probability of $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A^c\cap B^c)$ when given $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A\cap B^c)$=

Tags: probability

[image]

I am not sure how to approach this question. I tried multiplying $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ to get $P(A\cap B)$ but noticed that this won't work since $P(A)\times P(B^c)\neq\frac{1}{10}$. I don't think I can use inclusion-exclusion here since this question was introduced before we learned it.

I also tried ($\Omega$ is the sample space) $P(A)=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$, $P(B)=\frac{|B|}{|\Omega|}$ and $P(A\cap B^c)=\frac{|A\cap B^c|}{|\Omega|}$ to then rearrange it but I have 4 variables and don't know how to get something useful from $|A\cap B^c|$.

Comment: You correctly noticed that the multiplication rule $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ cannot be true in general.  We say that $A$ and $B$ are __independent__ when this equation happens to be true.  You'll probably learn about this later in whatever course you're taking or whatever book you're reading.  But you've already noticed an important fact that people sometimes forget: events aren't always independent!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

To answer the first question, notice that

\begin{align*}
A & = A\cap\Omega\\\\ & = A\cap(B\cup B^{c})\\\\
& = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^{c})
\end{align*}
Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A) & = \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c}) \\\\
& \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c})
\end{align*}

In order to answer the second question, observe that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c}) & = \mathbb{P}((A\cup B)^{c})\\\\
& = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A\cup B)\\\\
& = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

There are $ 4 $ distinct regions of $ \Omega $: $ A \cap B $, $ A \cap B ^ \complement $, $ A ^ \complement \cap B $, and $ A ^ \complement \cap B ^ \complement $.  I'll use $ p $, $ q $, $ r $, and $ s $ for these, respectively.  You're told that $ p + q = 1 / 4 $, that $ p + r = 8 / 1 0 $, and that $ q = 1 / 1 0 $.  Since the probabilities always sum to $ 1 $, you also have $ p + q + r + s = 1 $.  This is now a simple system of $ 4 $ equations to solve for the $ 4 $ probabilities.  Ultimately, you're being asked for $ p $ and $ s $.

Here's a picture of $ \Omega $:
[image]
You're told that the size of the top two regions sums to $ 1 / 4 $, that the size of the left two regions sums to $ 8 / 1 0 $, and that the size of the upper right region is $ 1 / 1 0 $.  And as always, the size of the entire region sums to $ 1 $.  Now you can find the size of every region with a little subtraction.  And you're being asked for the size of the upper left region and for the size of the lower right region.